# Silverlight combobox blocks interaction with other controls

Tags: c#, silverlight, combobox, popup

I have a Silverlight view which has several layers of popups.  It is a record search/edit page, which displays the results in a datagrid.  There is a details view for each record that is then shown in a popup over the grid.  Finally, the sections in the details view can be edited, and the edit form is displayed in a third popup.  The search criteria is hidden when viewing data, but can be toggled into view.

[image: Screenshot of the general layout]

The problem I am facing is that whenever the comboboxes on the edit popups are interacted with, it causes the layers below them to be un-clickable.  In the screenshot I provided, if the user clicks on the Phone or Email comboboxes, even if they don't change the selections, and closes the topmost edit popup, then the delete, save, close, and view on map buttons no longer receive mouse interaction.  They have mouseover styles that are not applied and they don't receive clicks.  However, the New Group button does, but only below a certain point.  It is behaving as if there is an invisible canvas/shape blocking mouse interaction.

Additionally, if the user slides out the Record Search panel (by clicking on the down arrow icon), the form somehow gets reset and those buttons are clickable again.  Also, if the browser window gets resized the buttons are also clickable.

I've spent the better part of two days going through this, admittedly complicated, view and I'm positive there are no controls/canvases/shapes that I'm displaying that are being placed in the way, as I've added color/outlines to every canvas in the xaml.

At this point I am stumped and reconsidering redesigning the form to avoid this problem. Has anyone run into this and if so do you have a solution?

Comment: No solution, very sorry.  But I would strongly recommend, if you have not done so, reducing this down to the simplest scenario that replicates the problem.  Make a copy of the solution and start hacking it apart.  Feels like a genuine SL bug.  I'd be fascinated to find out what you discover.